# Sharing a big String between an app and its extension

Tags: string, swift

I have a text file of 5MB and I need to send from my application to a content blocker extension. I tried a simple group sharing but it's not working, ehre is the code.

In my app:

```
listText = NSString(data: content, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
print("\(list): \(listText.characters.count)") // It works
if let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.AG.App") {
    print("In the group") // It works
    userDefaults.setObject(listText, forKey:"test")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

In my extension:

```
if let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.AG.App") {
    // Things happen here
    if let test = userDefaults.stringForKey("test") {
        // Nothing happens here
    }
}
```

How would you do to share a big amount of text between an app and its extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you load the string from a file and you already use App Groups, I suggest to save that file in the shared container and retrieve its content in the extension.

You can save file in the shared group in the same way you do for your app container. You only have to get the URL for the group root:

*Swift*

```
let groupRoot = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("com.group.Armand-Grillet")
```

*Objective-C*

```
NSURL *groupRoot = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"com.group.Armand-Grillet"];
```

You can't retrieve the string because you set a `NSString` and you try to retrieve an array, try to use `stringForKey:`

Comment: The `arrayFroKey` instead of `stringForKey` was an error in the copy of my code sample, it's also not working with `stringForKey`. Could you explain me more how to save the file in the shared container?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I'll put the swift code asap.